# Ошибка LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Требуется отделить реализацию шаблонного класса (Set) в файле Set.cpp от её заголовочного файла Set.h.
Содержание файлов:

Set.h:

```
template <class T>
class Set
{
    int reserve_;
    int capacity_;
    BitScale bitScale_;
    T **array_;
public:
    Set(int reserve = 256);
};
```

Set.cpp:

```
template <class T>
Set<T>::Set(int reserve) :
    reserve_(reserve)
    , capacity_(0)
    , bitScale_(reserve)
    , array_(new T*[reserve_])
{}
```

В файле main.cpp не удаётся создать множество командой: `Set<A> set1;`, где А - структура:

```
struct A {
    int id;
};
```

Возникает ошибка компоновки:

```
Ошибка  LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: __cdecl Set<struct A>::Set<struct A>(int)" (??0?$Set@UA@@@@QEAA@H@Z) в функции main
```

Подскажите, как правильно отделять реализацию от заголовочного файла в шаблонных классах? И почему моё разделение неверно? Спасибо.

Comment: Правильно их не разделять. В крайнем случае можно явно инстанцировать несколько специализаций.

Comment: Т.е. особенностью шаблонных классов, является то, что их не стоит предварительно объявлять в заголовочных файлах?  Разве удобно будет в больших проектах #include такие файлы с большой реализацией? Неужели для шаблонов нет решения?

Comment: Особенность их в том, что компилятор будет пытаться требовать наличия реализации шаблона в каждой единице трансляции, где этот шаблон инстанцируется. В больших проектах продвинутые разработчики вообще всю реализацию размещают в заголовочных файлах, не только для шаблонов.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ. Теперь стало яснее!